# How popular is a select based on another in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm creating a categorization system. Parent categories are identified by `'parent_id' = 0`.And the child classes are related through the same parent_id, but receive the value of the parent class. I thought about creating a dynamic select where I select the parent category and based on the selected option, the other select is populated.

I created a select that receives all the parent categories.

**View**

```
<select class="form-control" name="categoryid" id="categoryid">
        @foreach($mlb as $mlbcategory)
        <option value="{{$mlbcategory->erp_mcid}}">{{$mlbcategory->erp_title}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
      $mlb = MlbCategory::where('erp_parentid', '=', NULL)->get();
      return view('admin.categoriesupdate')->with('cat', $cat)->with('mlb', 
      $mlb);
    }
```

So I'm trying to get the value from select and pass to the controller where I can return the child category.

```
$('select[name=categoryid]').change(function () {
  var categoryid = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: {{route('categories::postForm')}},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#categoryid').val(data.categoryid);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
});
```

**Function to get value**

```
 public function getFilha(Request $request)
    {
      $data= $request->id;

     return response()->json($data);
    }
```

But it does not return anything, my idea is to manipulate this value received in the controller and return the values of the child class, any suggestions?

Comment: Try returning an array for your ajax request, it's very hard to convert a single value to a json object. `return response()->json(['data' => $data]);`

Comment: you aren't sending any data in your ajax post

Comment: I'll edit my question, I've already found where my biggest doubt is.

Comment: why? @charlietfl

Comment: why? because there is no `data` property in the settings object so nothing is posted

Answer (score 0):

So from what I see is that there is no data being send to your controller.

**Javascript**

```
$('select[name=categoryid]').change(function () {
    var categoryid = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: {{route('categories::postForm')}},
        data: {'categoryId':categoryid},
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#categoryid').val(data.categoryid);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

You can now access categoryId in your **controller**:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $categoryId = $request->input('categoryId');
  ....
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer, but for example, how to check those values in the controller? For example, I used dd ($ categoryId); And he did not return anything to me.

Comment: Anyway - try to debug the javascript side a bit more, checking if categoryid actually holds the value you want to send, the values are posted as requested and then we'll get into the controller.

Comment: I put a 'console.log(data)' after success but nothing returns, just a message about my token

Comment: Before the $.ajax call console.log(categoryid); - Then check the actual posted headers in the web-inspector. If those are all ok, you can continue to check the routes, controller and eventually the returning value.